# elasticsearch query to display lag time between two datetime fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have setup a dashboard that displays incoming message rates in a graph, filtered terms in a pie graph and all with nothing really to do. I want to be able to display a table/graph or some other type of panel to display elapsed time between two datetime fields that appear in my message:

```
{"pubDate":"2014-02-27T07:11:44",
 "fetchDate":"2014-02-27T07:11:55",
 "client":"ME",
 "query":"(work OR my job boring OR mundane OR stodgy OR interesting 
     OR sucks OR exciting OR fun)",
 "lang":"en"}
```

What I am able to get now is a language filter graph, and a query filtered pie chart with the normal incoming rate graph as well. I want to create a graph/table that gives the difference between the pubdate and fetchdate. Is this possible?

- Also related to same project is that the query field does not work correctly in that elasticsearch seems to break long queries into individual terms and I wonder if it interperates the OR itself or just based on length.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: you could try a ``script_fields``, which allow calculations with dates: ``curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/test/_search -d '{"query":{"match_all":{}}, "script_fields":{ "interval":{"script":"doc[\"fetchDate\"].value-doc[\"pubDate\"].value"}}}'``

Comment: Thanks for your response; still a newbie here and only setting up queries via kibana. Where do I do what you mentioned? In the main test.conf file in logstash?

Comment: I can see these types of scripts when I click on inspect on the panel but how do I create my own or edit one.